# Ajax success if inArray breaks a href appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I just thought I was very clever.  Turns out I was wrong.

My ajax login works fine.  I'm using it to append the username to a link which also works brilliantly.

Within a subset of pages I'd like it to refresh the page.  This also works brilliantly.

However, the refresh stops the href being appending.  I checked it and I can see the username?="username here" is working and it's immediately changed to username?=

I figure the reload would only happen in the cases when the if statement is true.?

```
        if(data.success == true){

            var thisPage = window.location.pathname;
            var refreshArray = new Array("training_chap01.php","training_chap02.php")
            if(jQuery.inArray(thisPage,refreshArray)){
                location.reload();

            }
            $('#loggedIn').show();
            $('a[href="userProfile.php?username="]').each(function(){
                this.href += username;
            });

            $('#loginContent').slideToggle();
            $('#loggedOut').hide();
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inArray` returns an index, not a boolean value, try this:

```
if(jQuery.inArray(thisPage,refreshArray) > -1)
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: You can add as answer if this is what helped you.